# Foreach em variável que recebe tickets da api do Zendesk

Tags: php

Estou recebendo tickets pela api do Zendesk, mas não sei como dar um foreach no resultado dando um echo nos índices.

```
$subdomain = "meusubdominio";
$username  = "email@email.com";
$token     = "xxx";
$client = new ZendeskAPI($subdomain);
$client->setAuth('basic', ['username' => $username, 'token' => $token]);
$getTickets = $client->tickets()->findAll();
```

Como eu dou um foreach na $getTickets, pra dar um echo nos índices ? Por exemplo, eu quero dar um echo em todos os índices ["url"].

Eu sei que o exemplo abaixo está errado, mas é pra exemplificar o que eu gostaria de fazer com os resultados.

Eu imagino que tenha que fazer algum tratamento na $getTickets antes de obter esse resultado. Só não sei o que deve ser feito.

```
Ex: 
foreach($getTickets as $Tct):
echo "<p>{$Tct['url']}</p>";
endforeach;
```

Se eu der um var_dump nela, eu tenho os resultados como:

```
object(stdClass)#53 (4) { ["tickets"]=> array(11) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#45 (31) { ["url"]=> string(50) "https://......
```

Comment: Então parece que o `foreach` deve ser em `$getTickets->tickets`

Comment: Muito obrigado, é isso mesmo. Resolveu!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embora eu não conheça a API Zendesk, pela estrutura do objeto que você deu saída no **var_dump**, talvez isso funcione:

```
foreach ($getTickets->tickets as $ticket) {
   echo "<p>{$ticket->url}</p>";
};
```

Verifique se dessa maneira funciona. Caso contrário, cole aqui a saída completa de um **print_r($getTickets)**, para entendermos melhor a estrutura do objeto.

Comment: Muito obrigado, é isso mesmo. Resolveu!